# Capybara 'first' selector not working

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara, automated-tests

In my test case I have a few similar buttons from which I'm trying to select and click the first one. When I use `find('a.add-link').click` it gives me ambiguous match error, which is expected, but when I try using `find('a.add-link').first.click`, it still claims it's an ambiguous match.

Also, if I try using something like `first('a.add-link').click`, it doesn't find the selector.

Another method I found somewhere using `find('a.add-link', match: :first).click` also doesn't work, it says it's a wrong key

I'm using cucumber version 1.2.5

Comment: What is your default selector?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've managed to solve it by using

```
eventually do
  first('a.add-link').click
end
```